# python don't save files in visual studio code

Tags: python, python-3.x, visual-studio-code

I started to use visual studio code yesterday and i'm having this problem...

Let's suppose I have this code:

```
myFile = open("file.txt", "w+")
myFile.write("something \n")
myFile.close()
```

When I run it on VScode it don't save the file, but when I run it in SublimeText it does.

do you know how to solve it?. I didn't find anything (or I don't know how to search), my launch.json look like this:

```
{
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Python: Current File",
            "type": "python",
            "request": "launch",
            "program": "${file}",
            "console": "internalConsole"
        }
    ]
}
```

**After I wrote that I noticed that it saves the file in "C: \ Users \ User \ Documents \ vsprofiles", but I have my .py file on the desktop, I want it to save the file in the same path where the .py file is, like SublimeText does.

Comment: If you run `import os; print(os.getcwd())` does that matchup with the path you found?

Comment: @StevenSummers yes it does 

Comment: Try setting the current working directory then. I use `"cwd": "${fileDirname}"`

Comment: Go to settings and search for terminal and you will see cwd integrated something

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For completeness here is my config file

```json
"launch": {
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Python: Current File",
            "type": "python",
            "request": "launch",
            "program": "${file}",
            "console": "integratedTerminal",
            "cwd": "${fileDirname}",
            "env": {},
            "pythonArgs": [],
            "stopOnEntry": false
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: it worked!, i added "cwd": "${fileDirname}", at the end and it worked, thank you.